# Table that lets user select next section and only displays link to remaining sections?

Tags: jquery, forms, responsive

I'm not even sure how to explain what I want which is probably why I can't find any website to help me get started.

I want to create a webpage or standalone form/table that displays options in the first section, lets the user pick an option to display next section, and then only displays remaining options in that section and so on. I have an image that I think will be better at explaining than I am.

[image: Visual example]

Comment: the word you are looking for is "wizard", or "wizard form design" :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a wizard form design you can either code it from scratch or use a plugin. One of [these](http://www.sitepoint.com/6-jquery-form-wizard-plugins/) will do.

Comment: That's closer...but I want the user to be able to choose which section they go to next. And then have only the remaining section options display. I was only able to link to the image in my text so it's hard to notice, but maybe that would help explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: It may be possible that instead of actually allowing user to choose to which section to go, you should imitate this process. Behind the curtains you'll have certain sections from a to z, and will just change the content of that sections regarding to users choices. If that's not the case, sorry :)